# Hyperlink is undefined inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I have a HyperLink placing inside an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="LinkMylink" Text="B3D Download" Visible="False"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But then I got this problem:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ document.getElementById(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Link3Dlink)(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.initialize(); Uncaught ReferenceError: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkMylink is not defined //]]> </script>
```

It seems strange, is not it? What is the cause of this and how can I fix it? The javascript method is automatically generated.

Comment: Where is this exception happening? What is the code that is causing it?

Comment: in the Javascript method which is automatically generated somehow

Comment: IDK what your page/script is trying to do, but since that link has `Visible="False"` on it, then it won't render at all... so yes the script will not be able to find it by ID. Maybe try controlling the visibility with CSS.

Comment: How about using style="display:none" instead of visible ="false"

Comment: but then in the code behind, I would like to set it visible=true. If I used style="display:none" then I can not set it

Comment: You can wrap it in a css class and use "CssClass" property from code behind.

Comment: it is still showing the error with style="display:none". strange